# Free group and normal subgroups with corresponding schreier representatives.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a free group on $a$ and $b$. Let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $\mathbb{F}$ generated by $a^2,b^3$ and $(ab)^2$. Similarly $H$ is the normal subgroup generated by $a^2,b^3$ and $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

i) Show that $N\neq H$.

ii)Find Schreier representative for $\mathbb{F}$ mod $H$ and $\mathbb{F}$ mod $N$.

Comment: Just like that? Without a little "please", "if you don't mind" or something? What about showing some self effort, some own work??

Comment: hello @DonAntonio I never thought "please" could be an issue. Anyway, I tried to prove it by contradiction: if $N=H$ then $\mathbb{F}$ mod $H$ and $\mathbb{F}$ mod $N$ should be isomorphic. It is east to check $(ab)$ has order 6 in $\mathbb{F}$ mod $H$ but I couldn't find any element of order 6 in $\mathbb{F}$ mod $N$. I would be much obliged if you can provide some rigorous proof.

Comment: It's not "the please", but rather the direct commands "show", "find", etc., but even more important is the lack of displaying one's effort to solve one's own problem.

Comment: No, accepting an answer doesn't bump the question. –  Jonas Meyer Jan 3 '12 at 6:44

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Schreier representative, however there is some information I can provide.

$$F/N=\langle a,b \mid b^3,a^2,aba^{-1}=b^{-1}\rangle\cong D_6$$
$$F/H=\langle a,b \mid b^3,a^2,ab=ba \rangle\cong C_2\oplus C_3$$

Comment: I think you have made a mistake $N$ is not what I have mentioned. The laast relation should be $aba^{-1}=b$.

Comment: @shzan $(ab)^2=abab=1$ implies $aba=b^{-1}$. For $a^2=1$, we get the conclusion.

Comment: thats true but $b^{-1}\neq b$ as $b^3=1$

Comment: None of the two cases is correct: a subgroup of a free group is **always** free and neither the dihedrals nor that direct sum are free.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, I am wrong. I fix it.

Comment: Now that's way another thing, @gaoxinge. I agree with both cases **but** the first should be, imo, $\;D_3\cong S_6\;$ ...still a dihedral, of course. Check this. +1

Comment: @Shzan: $$1=(ab)^2=abab\implies aba=b^{-1}$$ and since $\;a^2=1\iff a=a^{-1}\;$ , the relation in gaoxinge's answer is correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for pointing out it.

Comment: Ahhh...sorry guys i was seeing $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ only, silly me

Comment: thanks to @gaoxinge, now i see why i was not able to find an element of order 6 in $F$ mod $N$. I hope someone can come up to prove that both have same shreier representatives.

Comment: @gaoxinge, the notation $S_{6}$ is usually reserved for the symmetric group on $6$ letters, whereas here you clearly mean the symmetric group on $3$ letters, that is, the dihedral group of order $6$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, a Schreier system of representatives for both subgroups should be provided by
$$
1, b, b^{2}, a, b a, b^{2} a
$$

*Addendum* The reason is that both quotient groups are a semidirect product of a cyclic group $\langle b \rangle$ of order three by a cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ of order $2$. Then one of them is abelian (and thus cyclic of order $6$) while the other is not (and thus isomorphic to the symmetric group on three letters, a.k.a. the dihedral group of order $6$).